# Migrating Sitecore 6.6 to Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore8

Recently `Sitecore 8` has released and it has came up with lot of exciting new features. So our team decided to move from `Sitecore 6.6 to Sitecore 8.` Before migrating, i would like to know what all things i should be having in handy. Such as, `.net Framework`, `Hardware configuration`, `environment` etc.

Also, i would like to know the procedure to migrate from 6.6 to 8? I, never involved in sitecore migration project before. Please suggest me some good articles or post here your thoughts.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5):

See the [Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164) for the .NET Framework, SQL Server version and Windows version.

Two common approaches.

1) Follow the Sitecore upgrade path.

2) Package the content, and start with a clean install.

Currently I working on a upgrade with an scripted upgrade that follow the Sitecore path. So I can easy repeat the steps and have the latest content in the databases.

I have some of my findings put down here [Sitecore update and modules](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/upgrade-and-modules.aspx) this article contain also a Related links section. Such as the upgrade white paper from [Varun](https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/sitecore-version-upgrade-whitepaper/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how 'cluttered' your existing instance is, you may also want to consider installing a fresh copy of Sitecore 8 and then migrate your data/code to avoid all the hops that would be necessary to get to 8.

Comment: Can u please elaborate? I'm new to this process/

Comment: @PaRsH: What you may want to do is install a brand-new copy of Sitecore as a new instance.  Then, identify anything that has been customized and see how to make those customizations (if neccessary) in the new instance.  Install and configure any needed modules.  Then work on generating packages to migrate the templates, layouts, renderings, etc to install in the new instance.  You'll need to weigh the effort of this against multiple-step upgrades, but it's sometimes cleaner to start fresh when you have to move so far.

Comment: That sounds great, but what if i want to move content from older version to newer version. Do i have to package those items and install it in new version?

Comment: @PaRsH: Yes, you would package the content along with the templates, layouts, etc.  Basically, everything inside of Sitecore that you want to have on the 'new' version.

Comment: Well, Thanks Craig. I will try. I will keep update in this post.

Answer (score 1):

May be the following blog might help. Take a look at it.
https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/sitecore-version-upgrade-whitepaper/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make a backup of your site to use as a "sandbox" for the upgrade. Copy your databases and the web root for your site to a new location and then set up an IIS site with appropriate permissions pointing to your copy, and change your connection strings in the copy to point to a copy of the databases you backed up.

Perform the update there and ensure everything is working correctly. Work slowly to make sure you are following instructions correctly and note any special actions you had to take to perform the upgrade. Once you have it upgraded, perform the same process on the "real" site.

If you work with a Sitecore partner, I would highly encourage you to discuss the process with them to learn more specifics about the risks and challenges you may encounter during your upgrade.